# How to add Normalize CSS to Storybook?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, storybook

I'm trying to add the [Normalize.css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalize.css) from node_modules but it doesn't work.
I have tried everything, from a custom configuration for webpack (I'm using version 5 for my React project), to importing it into the preview.js and preview-head.html, but I can't get it to work, Storybook still keeps putting me the browser styles and it's very frustrating, because in my React project I want to use a css normalizer.

Can someone give me an example of how it would be done? Since what I have found in the documentation and on the internet has not helped me or I have not known how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try put the `style` tag in `preview-head.html`

Like this:

```
<style>
  /* copy-paste normalize code hire */
  html {
        line-height: 1.15;
        -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  }
  ...
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The storybook docs mention importing your css in preview.js
https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/styling-and-css#importing-css-files

> To use your CSS in all stories, you import it in .storybook/preview.js

```js
// ./storybook/preview.js
import 'normalize.css';
```